# DSL process reply from activeMQ

Tags: java, apache-camel

Referring to: http://camel.apache.org/jms.html

I'm trying to handle a reply in request-reply mode of an active MQ queue. Here is the code form the page above:

I have tried to do this:

```
                from("file://C:\\Users\\Thom\\git\\brms-poc-esb\\rule-cancel\\data").
                    log("Processing ${file:name}").
                    process(requestProcess).
                    log("Generated ${body}").
                    to(queueUri).inOut().
                    process(new ResultProcess());
```

When I process this, I am still getting the stream I sent to my active MQ.

How do I process the reply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.to(ExchangePattern.InOut, queueUri)` as using `inOut()` after `.to()` as you do is deprecated.

Or you can also do

```
.setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOut)
.to(queueUri)
```

eg to set the pattern before calling the to endpoint.

You can always use the tracer to see what happens during routing, that can help you understand: http://camel.apache.org/tracer